# Is the Universal Wavefunction a sensible ontological concept?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, universe, quantum-interpretations

It seems to me that several quantum interpretations rely on the idea that there exists a [wavefunction that completely specifies the state of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_wavefunction). Of these, the Many Worlds Interpretation is perhaps the most famous but it seems even the Bohm Interpretation requires a Universal Wavefunction in order to specify the complete, nonlocal waveguide that determines the trajectories of locally isolated particles.

This Universal Wavefunction is difficult to explicitly construct as it requires a specification of a complete set of observables. However, one can imagine that in the limit of infinite experiments, it might be possible to enumerate a complete set of observables and determine the form of the Universal Wavefunction on these observables (or more specifically on some maximal subset of commuting observables).

The difficulty I'm encountering is that I do not see how this limit necessarily converges to a fully specified Universal Wavefunction. Just considering how the final object would have to be constructed, a simple paradox immediately arises: There must be a self-encoding (i.e. a model) of the Universal Wavefunction within a subset of itself. This model would be constructed using strictly less information than the "real" Universal Wavefunction. Naively this seems not only unlikely to me, but completely contradictory. One could consider the universe itself as the model, but this is not a representation of the universe and it contains no physical content about its laws or any means of prediction.

It's clear that some approximate model might exist in a subset of the Universal Wavefunction, but a number of these quantum interpretations rely on the existence of such a wavefunction in order to justify their ontological ramifications. Often the stipulation is made, "if calculated from an outside observer," but it isn't fair to assume that an "observer outside the universe" is a sensible ontological framework to work with either.

I haven't really been able to find discussions of the Universal Wavefunction from this angle, are there any resources that are able to define the Universal Wavefunction in such a way and circumvent (or show the potential naive flaw of) my concerns?

Is there an argument that such a Universal Wavefunction need not exist in order to carry out the program implied by these interpretations?

Are the ontological pictures of Bohmian mechanics and the many worlds interpretation insensitive to the existence of a Universal Wavefunction in the first place?

I apologize if this is a repost but similar questions seem to be focused on the existence of the many worlds that follow from this stipulation in the many worlds interpretation or whether the universal wavefunction exists and neither approach seem to be getting at my question.

Comment: Is your objection specific to quantum mechanics? In classical mechanics, the analog of the "universal wavefunction" is just a set of real numbers specifying the position of all the particles. But presumably this also contains too much information to be described within the universe itself (or a subset of it).

Comment: In classical mechanics this is equivalent to Laplace's Demon for which there are proofs showing that you cannot construct Laplace's Demon in the first place (with certain definitions). Special relativity might introduce some complications but I think the situation is mostly the same. My objection is thus specific to the quantum case, but if there is contention with the classical case, I suppose that too would be worthy of discussion.

Comment: Isn't this like saying 'I don't believe the earth is a single planet, because that would mean that a geology textbook describes the whole earth, but the geology textbook is just a small part of earth and so can't contain a description of the whole?'

Comment: It is, you shouldn't expect the geography book to have a complete description of every particle on Earth's position and momenta. That is indeed the inference.

Comment: For a constructivist approach, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06845

Comment: See also http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005095

Comment: Thank you Stéphane Rollandin, those are the kinds of discussion I had in mind. Fink and Leschke seem to be interpreting the Universal Wavefunction in the context of a minimal interpretation, specifically Ballentine's ensemble interpretation, and their objections are based on the grounds that a Universal Wavefunction cannot be imagined as the consistent preparation of any kind of ensemble, abstractly or physically. My qualm aligns with their point on page 3, "the universe cannot remain in the same state as before a measurement and, at the same time, exhibit the result of this measurement."

Comment: Continued....However their argument is in regards to establishing a suitable ensemble to construct the Universal Wavefunction and is not a criticism about the self-consistency of such a wavefunction. I think they misinterpret the "ensemble" in this interpretation. While it may not be possible to prepare an ensemble of the universe in practice, its genesis can be regarded as a consistent preparation process. Thus assigning it a quantum state is sensible. In practice, one could consider the set of all wavefunctions which are consistent with all set of experimental facts and that would suffice.

Comment: Bolotin's paper seems to be more in line with the kind of criticism I'm making but in a strictly recursive constructability paradigm. I think if my criticism would apply in this argument under the assumption the universe is finite, the Universal Wavefunction would still be unrealizable. If instead the requirements of radical recursive constructability were dropped, my concern about the content of the Universal Wavefunction would still stand as that limit may not be definable even with a looser sense of constructability. Is there a named program or field which these papers fall under?

Comment: Daniel, in my analogy, the "single planet" is analogous to the universal wavefunction. The geology textbook is just someone's description of it. My point is that it's like saying 'the part can't contain the whole, therefore the whole doesn't exist'.

Comment: Even assuming the textbook can store the positions and momenta of all of Earth's particles at a given time, it does not have the ability to predict those positions and momenta at all other times. In this example of Laplace's Demon, the "whole" does not exist since there is no inference device that admits a complete description of the planet for all time. The "whole" isn't the planet itself, it's the planet's complete description. Geology does not need to represent all of the Earth's particles in order to effectively describe the Earth though.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot make sense of your argument. When you say, does it make sense as an *ontological* concept, I assume you mean, does it make sense for a "universal wavefunction" to be an independently existing physical thing. But then you bring up all this stuff about constructibility and limits and so on. None of that has any bearing on whether or not something can exist, only on how well we can represent it.

Comment: A wavefunction is a specific mathematical object. The universe may not have a consistent, complete representation as a wavefunction, despite the fact that subsets of the universe do have such representations. If no such description of the universe exists, we cannot safely assume that the universe has the properties of a wavefunction. The formulation of several quantum interpretations require the universe to have these properties, thus the consistency of the Universal Wavefunction is a question of ontology, at least within these interpretations.

Comment: Still can't sympathize with your perspective. Suppose, like Hawking, I say the universal wavefunction assigns an amplitude to every possible spacelike classical configuration of the universe, obtained by a path integral over histories ending with that configuration...

Comment: One may ask whether this is a well-defined prescription, but the reasons to question would be like the usual technical reasons in calculus, topology... why something might be ill-defined, e.g. because it doesn't converge; not your paradox of self-description or your remark about limits of sets of observables...

Comment: You seem to be seeking problems for the very concept of universal wavefunction, that arise from the role of observers in quantum mechanics, but neither of your proposed problems make sense to me.

Comment: This isn't an issue of the convergence of any specific algorithm, I'm questioning  if there exists any well-defined prescription at all. If the object is inherently self-contradictory, then it doesn't matter what prescription we choose. You seem to be skeptical of the claim that Laplace's demon is self-contradictory, I cannot really convince you of that here. All I can ask is if you would accept that Laplace's Demon is self-contradictory, how does the Universal Wavefunction escape its pitfalls? And if it doesn't, why can we assume it still can be operated on as if such a wavefunction exists?

Comment: have you not heard of the density matrix formulation  for many particle systems  ? http://inspirehep.net/record/230416

Answer (score 2):

I agree with some of the comments that the Universal Wavefunction $\Psi$ is in no principle way different to a collection of all positions and momenta $(p_i,q_i)$, for $i=1,...,N$, where $N$ is the number of particles in the universe. The latter would be the "full description" of the state of the universe in classical mechanics.

Of course, if we seriously write down a theory (classical mechanics/quantum mechanics), we postulare some mathematical objects ($p_i$ and $q_i$/$\Psi$) for the description of our world. Some people might even claim they *exist*, and then we have the word ontology in the games.
But even more clearly, no one thinks that these can be *known*, or *written down explicitly*, or whatever.

It is not a problem: Why should we even think that we can fully know anything that exists? It is very similar to the oceans on earth: Before people could fly, nobody had seen more than very small parts of the ocean, and everybody saw different parts. It was, however, the natural assumption that actually all the space between, say, Europe and America, is filled with water and the Atlantic ocean actually exists.
This is a simpler concept than anything else I could think of to explain what we see.

In the same way, we assume that the whole universe is described by a wave function because the use of wave functions for all kinds of subsystems of the universe has proven very fruitful. Where would you stop, what should be the largest system that still has a wave function? Since the whole universe is the only real "isolated system" that there is, we need at least in principle to consider it as a whole. For all practical purposes, of course, this is an irrelevant question. For ontology, the question is then more if the mathematical objects as $\Psi$ are really "there" or just a convenient invention by us. Maybe this latter opinion suits you better.

Comment: Inferring the existence of the whole universe does not also allow us to infer it has a wavefunction or the properties of one. Even if you assume the mathematical wavefunctions are "there," an inconsistent wavefunction for the Universe is still an issue. Take MWI for example, if you cannot assume that the Universal Wavefunction  branches in environmentally-selected eigenstates, you cannot postulate the existence of other worlds. If this were true, MWI would not be problematic for interpreting specific experiments, but it couldn't serve as an ontology for the universe.

Comment: Maybe it's true that Many-Worlds are problematic, but if you take e.g. Bohmian mechanics, no problems arise.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how Bohmian mechanics avoids this. If you cannot assume that the Universe has the properties of a wavefunction, how do we have an ontological basis for the universal pilot wave that determines the complete set of particle trajectories?